# Harmonic maps of Euclidean space to the sphere

Tags: riemannian-geometry

What are some examples of non-constant harmonic maps from Euclidean 3-space with its usual metric, punctured at a discrete set of points, to the 2-sphere with its usual metric?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for those that surjects onto the sphere? Or those with differentials that are rank 2? (I edited in a requirement of non-constant, but there's of course still those that maps onto a single geodesic; I assume those are not interesting to you?)

Comment: @WillieWong: thanks. Yes, surjective, thanks.